# How can I set JSlider ticker to start at the begining of the slider (in Java)?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jslider, ticker

The title pretty much explains my question.

I'm adding a URL to an image that explains my question better just in case i'm not clear.

I think I'm missing some obvious method, maybe you guys could help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `I think I'm missing some obvious method,` - how about the constructor for the JSlider. It allows you to specify the min, max, initial values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `slider.setValue(0);` after you have initialized it and probably before you add it

Make sure you have a read through [How to use sliders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) for more details

Comment: +1 for the tutorial link. Its shows how to specify the min, max, initial values when you create the JSlider.